# How to use variables in SQL Lite transaction (web kit browser local database)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an array with variables with values from textfields

```
var data = [name, address, city, country];
```

then the command

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Customer(name, address, city, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]]);
```

It works fine but in the real database I have about 50 fields and if I need to add for example three more I have to add three question marks, three data[n] and so on and it's quite error prone so I thought I would create it in a loop instead.

I have the array:

```
var data = [name, address, city, country];
```

The loop:

```
var columns = "";
var questionMarks = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    columns += "data[" + i + "], ";
    questionMarks += "?, ";
}

columns = columns.slice(0, -2);
questionMarks = questionMarks.slice(0, -2);
columns = "[" + columns + "]";
```

I can use questionMarks in the command like:

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Customer(name, address, city, country) VALUES (" + questionMarks + ")", [data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]]);
```

But when I try to use columns as well it doesn't work

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Customer(name, address, city, country) VALUES (" + questionMarks + ")", columns);
```

also tried

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Customer(name, address, city, country) VALUES (" + questionMarks + ")", + columns);
```

I did document.write(columns) and it looks exactly the same as

```
[data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]]
```

What am I doing wrong with columns?

Thanks in advance

I guess questionMarks works becasue it is a string but the data[n] values are not a part of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just not go the ? mark route and build out the exact SQL to run.  You don't have to use that technique.  Just build out the exact SQL string you want to run

```
var data="name='fred',address='90210',city='city',country='country'";
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Customer(name, address, city, country) VALUES (" + data + ")", {}]);
```

but build the data string out dynamically.